# SqlAlchemy базовая модель без сохранения и внешние ключи

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Нужно сделать несколько таблиц с одинаковыми стоблцами.
Каждая таблица соответствует одному типу отделений (МФЦ, ГИБДД и т.п)

1) Нужно сделать так, чтобы эти модели наследовались от базовой, но базовая не хранилась в БД.

2) Нужно сделать так, чтобы внешние ключи из данных таблиц ссылались на три таблицы M (Регион, Район, Округ). Проблема встает в том, что во внешней модели M нужно указывать, какие таблицы ссылаются на неё через relationship. Как сделать relationship на несколько таблиц из одной?

Может быть, у меня неправильная схема БД.

Я просто только начал изучать, и не могу найти как такое сделать. Приветствуется ответ где просто указана ссылка.

**UPD: Схема данных**

Таблица `Department` представляет собой типовую таблицу, на каждый тип будет такая отдельная к примеру `DepartmentMFC`, `DepartmentGIBDD`.

Отношения (Редактор попался не очень):
Region-Department : 1M
County-Department : 1M
Distinct-Department: 1M
Department-Service: MM

REM: По первому вопросу вроде бы надо использовать [Mixin class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html).

[image: Схема БД]

Comment: Добавьте текущую схему БД для наглядности и то что хотите получить.

Comment: @TheMarhang обновил вопрос.

Comment: [Примеры](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/dynamic_dict/dynamic_dict.html) и [FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) Читали?

Comment: @TheMarhang не нашел ничего подходящего.

Comment: @TheMarhang, в общем, здесь придется для каждой связаной модели создавать свою таблицу. Иначе придется отказаться от использования внешних ключей.

Comment: зачем? у вас Родительские таблицы - `Region`, `County` и `Distinct` дочерняя таблица - `Department `

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97677/discussion-between-the-marhang-and-olegup).

Answer (score 0):

Наследование есть в примерах. В вашем случае похоже на:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

class Catalog(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)


class Region(Catalog):
    __tablename__ = 'region'
    __table_args__ = (sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),)
    departaments = orm.relationship("Departament", back_populates="region")


class Departament(Base):
    ...
    region_id = sa.Column('region', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('region.id'))
    region = orm.relationship("Region", back_populates="departaments")
```

При создании методов в `Catalog`, не забывайте их оборачивать `@declared_attr`.
С разными таблицами `DepartamentX` сложнее. Либо создавать соответсвующее количество отношений. Может быть разумно, если их количество крайне ограниченно и неизменно. Либо менять схему, что на мой взгляд правильно

```py
class DepartamentType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'departament_type'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)

class Departament(Base):
    ...
    type_ = sa.Column('dtype', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('departament_type.id'))
```